# IRC Username as Forums Username

Tags: php, html, mysql, iframe, irc

Hello I've recently got a embed from Quakenet for my IRC Channel. I've changed the nick thingy to `$member[members_display_name]` but it displays that long string, not the username of the Forums User as I expected?

Comment: Found a solution via Google :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're missing an echo statement:

```
<iframe src="http://webchat.quakenet.org/?nick=<?php echo $member['members_display_name']; ?>&channels=craft101&uio=MTM9dHJ1ZQa9" width="647" height="400">
```

Comment: Thanks but now the nickname is the echo statement xD

Comment: @LukeKitto Is it possible to have the page be in a `.php` file rather than a `.html` file? If not, try adding the following line to your .htaccess file: `AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm`

Comment: Moved file to /forums/page/chat.php, changed file extension to .php but that ended with same result, changed the Content Type setting in IP.Content from Raw HTML to Raw PHP and that threw a error at me when I tried to access the page "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/nzstore/public_html/craft101.info/forums/admin/applications_addon/ips/ccs/sources/pages.php(167) : eval()'d code on line 1", .htaccess method didn't work

Comment: @LukeKitto Don't change the type to raw PHP unless you want to put everything in an `echo` statement. Is the `iframe` tag the only thing in the file?

Comment: Yes... Only the embed code I got from QuakeNet IRC (which was that iframe)

Comment: @LukeKitto If you're using raw PHP, then you might just be able to make the file `echo '<iframe src="http://webchat.quakenet.org/?nick=' . $member['members_display_name'] . '&channels=craft101&uio=MTM9dHJ1ZQa9" width="647" height="400">'`

Comment: That led to another error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting ',' or ';' in /home/nzstore/public_html/craft101.info/forums/admin/applications_addon/ips/ccs/sources/pages.php(167) : eval()'d code on line 1"

Comment: @LukeKitto Sorry. Should be `echo '<iframe src="http://webchat.quakenet.org/?nick=' . $member['members_display_name'] . '&channels=craft101&uio=MTM9dHJ1ZQa9" width="647" height="400">';`

Comment: Works! But it's changed from no connection dialog (just a Join button) to the default dialog where users can select their Nickname and modify the channels they join... But the Nickname box is blank (not prefilled?) I wanted them to just join with their Forums Username... Like http://old.pokefarm.org/chat.php

Comment: Tested this with Mibbit and it also returns a blank username

Comment: @LukeKitto Most likely `$member['members_display_name']` is empty, then.

Comment: I don't think so as that is the column which stores the members display names

Comment: Plus I'm a noob at MySQL so I don't think I'll know another solution sorry